# MySQL Cumulative Total

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

A company rewards one of its employees every day.  The data is maintained in a table called `REWARDS`.  As shown in the sample data below, we have one row per day in the table with the following structure:

(Sorry for the poor table formatting)

```
REWARD_DATE EMP_ID  REWARD_AMT
1-Jan-15    101       400
2-Jan-15    102       300
3-Jan-15    101       700
4-Jan-15    102       500
5-Jan-15    103       100
```

Can you write a query to report the running totals as the following?

```
REWARD_DATE #EMP    TOT_REWARD_AMT
1-Jan-15    1            400
2-Jan-15    2            700
3-Jan-15    2           1400
4-Jan-15    2           1900
5-Jan-15    3           2000
```

Comment: What's the datatype of `REWARD_DATE`?

Comment: Unlike some other RDBMS, MySQL doesn't support analytic functions (which would make this task a breeze).  Whilst it can still be done using hacks involving user variables, you're probably best off performing calculations of this sort higher up in your application code.

Comment: It is not necessary that this is perfomed in MySQL.  It can be any SQL environment.  REWARD_DATE is a numeric variable.

Comment: `REWARD_DATE`  numeric variable!!?? @James. I was expecting either `date` or `char`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this (slightly simplified now):

```
SELECT b.rdate, COUNT(distinct a.eid) empcnt, SUM(a.amnt) total
FROM tbl a
INNER JOIN tbl b ON b.rdate>=a.rdate
GROUP BY b.rdate
```

as demonstrated here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6871/2

Comment: This is eccentric! Nice way to handle this. :)

Comment: Well, just the most straightforward way. ;-)

Comment: To be honest I was thinking in another way (gradually moving towards complexity). And I really loved the way you handled the propagation of previous dates into the next dates.